# Wierd listview item selector appearance (pressed state was not removed when finger left the screen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

I have listview item like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/music_list_item_checkbox_bg"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

`music_list_item_checkbox_bg.xml` is a selector which will show different drawable depending the different state.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_check_untapped" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_check_tapped" />

    <item android:state_selected="false"  
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_uncheck_untapped" />

    <item android:state_selected="false"  
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_uncheck_tapped" />

</selector>
```

When i pressed the item in the listview and left the touch screen inside the item, the drawable depending on the different state is right.

***Question:*** But if i pressed the item and move the finger horizontally out of the item (The X of touch point is between the top and bottom of the item), then left the screen, the drawable of the checkbox will remain in the state of pressed. (If the X of touch point is out of the top and bottom of the item, the state is right).

I tried add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the checkbox to get the same state with the parent, but it not works.

I'm confused, Anyone have some ideas?

**Edited**

> I tried implements onTouch and onIntercept in the item before, but only can receive action down, if i return super.onTouch(MotionEvent event). Only return true, then the sequence event will received, but the onItemClick of listview could't worked.
>   I try to read the onTouch code snippet in the AbsListview to figure out how to resolve the problem, i found sometimes the press status of child(item) will not to clear to false by calling child.setPressed(false) which depending on the different touch mode.

I really really want an solution!!!

Comment: This is a pure guess, but perhaps it's because that motion registers a Down event on the view (pressed) but not a corresponding Up event for *that* view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem but maybe not a good solution or official solution.

I use my own `MyListView` class extends from `ListView` instead of the SDK `ListView` and receive the `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` in its `onTouchEvent`, then set the press state of the item to false manually. More details to see the below code.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    boolean handled = super.onTouchEvent(event);
    Log.d("test", "event " + event.toString());
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        m_downPosition = pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        Log.d("test", "The down position " + m_downPosition);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        int position = m_downPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View child = INVALID_POSITION != m_downPosition ? getChildAt(position) : null;
        if (null != child)
        {
            child.setPressed(false);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_check_tapped" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_check_tapped" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_uncheck_untapped" />
</selector>
```

try using these selector as background

Comment: if the above doesnt work after implement ontouch  and on identify the action up event and refresh the listview using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I solve the problem but maybe not a good solution or official solution.

Answer (score 1):

try making the views inside it not focussable...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/music_list_item_checkbox_bg"
android:focussableInTouchMode="false"
android:focussable="false"
    />
```

you cannot make a List item focussable in touch mode... here since your checkBox is focussable it creates problem...

Comment: I tried and it doesn't works. I use the android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to avoid the item get focused.

Comment: @dreamtale .. try removing **<item 
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_check_untapped" />** i don't think its even required since ListView item can not remain selected..

Comment: I removed and try the same code as you post, it still not works. This problem really frustrated me. I asked an engineer, and he found his gridview have the same problem. Maybe the listview or gridview want the same effect you wrote before have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try having a default selector item like this

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_checkbox_uncheck_untapped" />
```

and this will take care of all the remaining states
or you should have a selector item which takes care of the `focussed` states which is missing in your xml.

Comment: I have tried and it does't worked, Android lint also have a warning:No android:state_ attribute found on <item> 2, later states not reachable

Comment: hmm. i have this at the end, i.e after all other selector states. i dunno if that makes a difference. also did you try with  state_focussed

Comment: After seen the warning, i have tried moved it to the last, but unfortunately it still not worked, this problem drive me crazy. i have tried with 2 hours.

Comment: I solve the problem but maybe not a good solution or official solution.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `LinearLayout` for your item and override the `onTouch` in it. Handle the ACTION_CANCEL event(return true) and update the item's pressed and selected states.

```
class ItemLayout extends LinearLayout {

    @override
    boolean onTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch(ev.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_CANCEL: 
                // Update/reset pressed and selected states of item or checbkox
                return true;
        }
        return super.onTouch(ev);
    }

}
```

Refer http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/df75c5b8e4605167#

Hope that helps.

```
<ItemLayout 
  ....>
    <TextView
       ...
       />

    <CheckBox
       ...
       />
</ItemLayout >
```

Comment: My listview item is extends LinearLayout currently, I tried implements onTouch and onIntercept before, but only can receive action down, if i return super.onTouch(MotionEvent event), only return true, Then the sequence event will received, but the onItemClick of listview could't worked.

Comment: If return super, only action down can received in the item.

Comment: have done it same way as in code i have given? Check out the google groups link it says ACTION_CANCEL happens when finger goes out of view..

Comment: I tried before, remember the Action_cancel wasn't received, I will try again later and notify you if it received.

Comment: No, Action cancel also can't received. i nearly give up, Some time later, i will try to resolve it again.

Comment: I solve the problem but maybe not a good solution or official solution. Thanks for your focus on this question.